# Creating BitmapData and a sprite from it and possible performance differences

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, phaser-framework

I am making a HTML5 game using Phaser-framework.

I need to create a sprite that has one color and its alpha is set to below 1 so it can be seen through. Is there any performance difference between the two ways I thought of doing this?

Option 1: Creating a BitmapData with size 1x1, creating a sprite from this BitmapData object and then scaling the sprite to correct size:

```
var bitmapData = game.add.bitmapData(1, 1);
bitmapData.fill(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
var sprite = game.add.sprite(0, 0, bitmapData);
sprite.width = 1024;
sprite.height = 768;
```

Option 2: Creating BitmapData to the exact size it will be used and then creating a sprite from it:

```
var bitmapData = game.add.bitmapData(1024, 768);
bitmapData.fill(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
game.add.sprite(0, 0, bitmapData);
```

The purpose of this would be to color the whole game area with one color and be able to see what is behind.

Comment: Did you try to do a performance test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the thing that matters the most for performance is the size of the sprite you're drawing to the screen, no matter how you're loading or generating it before that, so these two should be performing equally well.

Comment: it probably won't perform equally well because bitmapdata uses another canvas in the background and that means that in #2 you're ~2 times slower.